# Error statement ignored and column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER T_CIM_INV_CAT1_HIS
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CIM_INV_CAT1
    REFERENCING NEW AS n OLD AS o
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    vCIC1_ID NUMBER ;
    vCIC1_SERIALNO_OLD VARCHAR2(20) := :o.CIC1_SERIALNO;
    vCIC1_SERIALNO_NEW VARCHAR2(20) := :n.CIC1_SERIALNO;
    vCIC1_ASSETNO_OLD NUMBER := :o.CIC1_ASSETNO;
    vCIC1_ASSETNO_NEW NUMBER := :n.CIC1_ASSETNO;
    vCIS_ID_OLD NUMBER := :o.CIS_ID;
    vCIS_ID_NEW NUMBER := :n.CIS_ID;
    vCIFCP_ID_OLD NUMBER := :o.CIFCP_ID;
    vCIFCP_ID_NEW NUMBER := :n.CIFCP_ID;
    vCIC1H_UPDATE_BY VARCHAR2(20) := :n.CIC1_UPDATE_BY;
    vCIC1H_UPDATE_DATE DATE := :n.CIC1_UPDATE_DATE;
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        vCIC1_ID := :n.CIC1_ID;     
    ELSE
        vCIC1_ID := :o.CIC1_ID;     
    END IF;

INSERT INTO CIM_INV_CAT1_HIS
(   CIC1H_ID, <----STATEMENT IGNORED
    CIC1_ID,
    CIC1_SERIALNO_OLD,
    CIC1_SERIALNO_NEW,
CIC1_ASSETNO_OLD,
    CIC1_ASSETNO_NEW,
CIS_ID_OLD,
CIS_ID_NEW,
CIFCP_ID_OLD,
CIFCP_ID_NEW,
    CIC1H_UPDATE_BY,
    CIC1H_UPDATE_DATE       )
VALUES
(   CENTORY_CIC1H_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     vCIC1_ID,
    vCIC1_SERIALNO_OLD,
    vCIC1_SERIALN0_NEW,
vCIC1_ASSETNO_OLD, <---COLUMN NOT ALLOWED
    vCIC1_ASSETNO_NEW,
vCIS_ID_OLD,
    vCIS_ID_NEW,
vCIFCP_ID_OLD,
    vCIFCP_ID_NEW,
    vCIC1H_UPDATE_BY,
    vCIC1H_UPDATE_DATE  );
END;
```

I got the error mentioned above. I already created sequence for CIC1H_ID. When I try to compile the query, the compiler log shows the errors.

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using? in some versions you cannot reference a sequence directly in an insert

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo, in line 42 of what you've posted (the one before the line you marked; think your counting in the PL/SQL section is off by one for both the annotations you made). This:

```
vCIC1_SERIALN0_NEW,
```

should be:

```
vCIC1_SERIALNO_NEW,
```

There is no local variable called `vCIC1_SERIALN0_NEW` (with a zero), so by default it's being interpreted as a (column) identifier, hence the error message.

Comment: thank you so much! I've been staring at this code for the whole day.